# Speech recognition API for android

Tags: android, webview

How can we use `Javascript` `speechRecognizer` API in `webview` for android. 
I have tried :-

```
window.SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;

recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
```

but here `SpeechRecognition()` constructor is not `recognised` and even `window.SpeechRecognition` is not defined.

Comment: Are you working with completely native or it is into ionic?

Comment: I am using it for android. Basic aim is to make it conpatible for all both platforms, Web as well as android thats why  I have used webview in android but webview is not able to recognize speechrecognition.

Comment: Doesn't it have Native Java APIs?

Comment: Already js code have been written for it using WEBRTC api for speech recognition. Now i am using the same code in my webview but my window attribute of webview doesnot have that property